# how to plot in spyder 3

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I upgraded OpenSuse from Leap 15.1 to Leap 15.2 and since then I can no longer generate plots with spyder3.

Example:
The following code does not create a plot on my system. Software versions:
python 3.6.10,
ipython 7.13.0

```
# circumvent basestring error message on start-up
    try:
      basestring
    except NameError:
      basestring = str

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly is not working? What are you expecting? What is happening?

Comment: It works in Spyder 4.1.4.  and IPython 7.16.1.  Have you upgraded recently?

Comment: The only output generated is one line with the name of the runfile. I expect this to be followed by a plot. I have upgraded to the latest version offered by the Leap 15.2 repositories.

Comment: It now works after installation of the Qt5 backend for python3-matplotlib

Comment: strange: it no longer works now. Have to invetigate